# mongoDB, finding a field that is NOT of a specific type

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have some legacy data that stored a string instead of an Object Id, I would like a way to FIND these records...

so as an example -

```
user : {
    _id: ObjectId('234wer234wer234wer')
    books_read: [
        {
           title: "Best book ever",
            _id: "123qwe234wer345ert456rty"
        },
        {
           title: "Worst book ever",
            _id: "223qwe234wer345ert456rty"
        },
        {
           title: "A Tail of Two Cities",
            _id: ObjectId("323qwe234wer345ert456rty")
        }
    ]
}
```

In this scenario, you can see 2 of the 3 books have _id of strings NOT ObjectIds... I want to update these to ObjectIds - but first I have to find them.

any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: `$type: "string"` would help: [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/type/)

Comment: excellent - thx